# Remotely Starting a Batch File

Tags: cmd, scheduled-tasks, remote-access

```
SCHTASKS /create  /S $strComputer  /tn "David\Start Gecko" /tr 
"'C:\eQube-Tools\Batch and Registry Files\gecko.bat'" /sc once /sd 
01/01/2099 /st 01:00 /u Boss /p *password* /RU SYSTEM

pause
SCHTASKS /run /S $strComputer /tn "David\Start Gecko"
```

So, I have a problem with running the batch file this creates, it says it's running on the task scheduler on the remote pc, but nothing happens. But the odd thing is: if I locally create a "basic task" it runs fine both remotely and running it by hand at that pc.

My question is there any way to have it know you want to create a "basic task" I've looked at the switches but can't find anything for /create, I also tried the /xml but this is something I plan to create, use then destroy so simpler the better.

** the reason I'm using SCHtasks is because I had a lot of issues with redirect errors trying to run it directly using powershell.

**Specs**

All win 7 WORKGROUP

All have matching Admin Accounts with matching password

Firewall set to allow remote sch tasks

Batch file is on remote pc

**the batch file I'm trying to run**

```
@echo off
c:
cd \eQube-Tools\Batch and Registry Files
start virtualhelpscreen.exe
:top
c:
cd \gecko
timeout 12 /nobreak
gecko.exe
cls
goto :top
```

Answer (score 0):

SCHTASKS /create /S $strComputer /xml "filesavedtomainpc" /tn "David\Start Gecko"

- one issue left is it not forcing full screen like it does when you run the batch file but that might be down to the program, for now the question I asked is answered.